# "With a crack like a whip" — common expression or not?

Tags: idioms, expressions

> With a crack like a whip, Dobby vanished.

I'm studying English using the Harry Potter books. I can't seem to find this expression in any  dictionary, however. Google returns no results at all (except for Harry Potter itself and one other, unknown, piece of writing).

So, is this a commonly used and/or existing and/or correct expression?

Comment: I think this is General Reference/Not Constructive. The meaning of "crack" here is trivial, given that one of the main purposes of a whip is to make a sudden cracking sound. And I *don't* think there's any point in ELU pontificating over *exactly how common* transparent expressions like this are.

Comment: You _are_ right. This is my mistake. I should've seen it myself...

Comment: We all sometimes fail to see the obvious, so I don't have a problem with the fact of you asking the question. I just think things like this should be answered in *comments*, and the question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a perfectly correct expression, but not very common in that form, perhaps because not many things crack like a whip! It's as good a simile as any though.

Comment: That's what I thought. My fault!

Comment: And *crack* as the name of the sound a whip makes is well attested. So whip crack-away, whip crack-away, whip crack-away!